Incorrect package="com.worldit.english" found in source AndroidManifest.xml In Expo EAS
We've been developing the app in React-Native. The problem that we got while building in Expo is
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Incorrect package="com.worldit.english" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /home/expo/workingdir/build/react-native/my-project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
  Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
  Recommendation: remove package="com.worldit.english" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /home/expo/workingdir/build/react-native/my-project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

And after that, gradle sends that:
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

But the problem is that I don't know how to access to AndroidManifest.xml in expo eas, because I don't even have android folder in my react-native project, previously I had successful build, but it was before.
I've tried recommended options in eas.json, but there was only 2 variants of event

Nothing Changed
Required Java 17, but I had Java 11 (Actually I had Java 22)

I also tried to change package name in app.json and even changed to recommended like in Expo documentations.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you fix it?
